# Update data from servlet

Tags: java, html, servlets

Trying to update info on the servlet page. But get HTTP 404 response(apache tomcat).

Dont know where is the problem

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class Update extends HttpServlet{
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
throws ServletException, IOException
{
    PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
    {
        res.setContentType("text/html");

            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>");
            out.println("Update Page");
            out.println("</title>");
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<table>");
        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet resultset = null;
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userdb";
        DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","root123");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","root123");
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        System.out.println("Database Successfully Connected");
        resultset = statement.executeQuery("select * from user_table");
    while(resultset.next())
    {
        out.println("<form action='update' method='post'>");
        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td>");
        out.println("<input type='text' name='name' value='" + resultset.getString(1) +"' / >");
        out.println("<td>");
        out.println("<input type='text' name='age' value='" + resultset.getString(2) +"' / >"); 
        out.println("<td>");
        out.println("<input type='text' name='height' value='" + resultset.getString(3) +"' / >"); 
        out.println("<td>");
        out.println("<input type='text' name='weight' value='" + resultset.getString(4) +"' / >");
        out.println("<td>");
        out.println("<input type='submit' value='Update' / >");
        out.println("</form>");
    }
    }
    catch(ClassNotFoundException ce)
    {
        out.println("Error " + ce);
    }
    catch(SQLException se)
    {
        out.println("Error " + se);
    }
    finally
    {
    try
    {
        connection.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    }
    }
    out.println("</table>");
    out.println("</body>");
    out.println("</html>");
    }
}



public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
throws ServletException,IOException
{
res.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
out.println("<html>");
out.println("<head>");
out.println("<title>");
out.println("Select Page");
out.println("</title>");
out.println("</head>");
out.println("<body>");
Connection connection = null;
Statement statement = null;

String name = req.getParameter("name");
String age = req.getParameter("age");
String height = req.getParameter("height");
String weight = req.getParameter("weight");

try
{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userdb";
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","root123");
statement = connection.createStatement();

String query = "update user_table set age='" + age + "', height='" + height + "', weight='" + weight + "' where name='" + name + "'";

int result = statement.executeUpdate(query);
out.println(result + " row(s) updated.");
}
catch(ClassNotFoundException ce)
{
out.println("Error " + ce);
}
catch(SQLException se)
{
out.println("Error " + se);
}
finally
{
try
{
connection.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}
}
out.println("</body>");
out.println("</html>");
}
}
```

The update button should direct to a page stated 1 rows updated.
I think its the query part or the declaration part.
there nothing wrong when compile just the result is just no as expected.
Hope there somebody will help with the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do the servlet mapping to an url

either by annotations

```
@WebServlet("/update")
public class Update extends HttpServlet{
 //...
{
```

or by setting it up in the **web.xml**

> ```
> <web-app>
>   <servlet>
>     <servlet-name>Update</servlet-name>
>     <servlet-class>com.something.Update</servlet-class> <!-- Your package --> 
>   </servlet>
>
>   <servlet-mapping>
>     <servlet-name>Update</servlet-name>
>     <url-pattern>/update</url-pattern>
>   </servlet-mapping>
> </web-app>
> ```